# What does it mean to add a virtual disk image to a virtual CD/DVD drive on a virtual machine?

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machine, virtualbox, disk

I'm currently installing virtual box, and one of the steps requires that I add a disk image (in my case, an ubuntu ISO file) to a virtual CD/DVD drive listed under the virtual machines Storage.

From what I understand the ISO basically contains all the contents of ubuntu. And once I've allocated enough disk space for my virtual machine, I need to install ubuntu by reading from this ISO file into my virtual hard drive.

So- is that the reason why I need to add the ISO image to my dvd/cd? Because it acts as an ACTUAL cd/dvd? My understanding is limited - I just want more clarification about this process!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.iso files are images of the entire content of a CD. They are meant to be burnt on a actual CD. But there are now several programs allowing to read the content of an .iso file without actually writing the data to a CD.

You're right in everything you said.
Virtual Box simulates (almost) everything of a real computer: disks, drives, memory, USB ports...
The drive is initially empty, i.e. has no CD/DVD inside.
Then you choose which CD should be simulated inside the drive. It can be either the actual CD on your physical machine, or a CD image, i.e. a .iso file.
When some program inside the virtual machine wants to access the data written on what it thinks is the CD, Virtual Box reads the .iso file and answer the program, as if the data came from a CD.

Answer (score 0):

Virtual box uses virtual drives.  These drives act as 'actual' drives on the guest OS, in your case Ubuntu would be the guest OS.

When you create a new virtual machine, it is clean, nothing has been installed yet.

In order to install Ubuntu on the machine you will need to load the ISO image into the virtual CD/DVD drive to install it.

Note: A ISO is a 'disk image' that contains the entire contents of a disk in a single file, that can be loaded into virtual drives, or burned to physical CD/DVDs

Here is a small tutorial on install Ubuntu to virtual box, the screen shots may differ a little bit, but the process will generally be the same for you.

http://osxdaily.com/2012/03/27/install-run-ubuntu-linux-virtualbox/